# Hashtables in C

Tags: c, hashtable

In this code I need to initialize, insert in a hashtable and print the values in these 2 stuctures:

- hashTable (number of nodes and a double pointer to the struct hashElem)
- hashElem (containing a char key and an int that counts every time there's been a node with the same key)

The error (see line in the print function) it gives me is this:
*warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char **' [-Wformat=]*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//GNU.txt at the end
#define m 89
 
typedef char *keyType;
typedef int valueType;
 
typedef struct hashElem{
    keyType *key;
    valueType freq;
}hashElem;
 
struct hashTable{
    int N;
    hashElem **array;
};
 
int hash(char *key, int i){
    int sum=0;
    while( *key!='\0' ){
        sum = sum + *key;
        key++;
    }
    return (sum+i)%m;
}
 
struct hashTable *createHashTable(){
    struct hashTable *ht=malloc(sizeof(struct hashTable));
    if( ht==NULL )
        printf("Error in memory allocation.\n");
 
    ht->N = 0;
    ht->array=malloc(m*sizeof(hashElem *));
    if( ht->array==NULL )
        printf("Error in memory allocation.\n");
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++ )
        ht->array[i] = NULL;
    return ht;
}
 
void freeHashTable(struct hashTable *ht){
    free(ht->array);
    free(ht);
}
 
void printHashTable(struct hashTable *ht){
    printf("Printing hash table without sorting:\n");
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
        if( ht->array[i]!=NULL )
            printf("%s: %d\n", ht->array[i]->key, ht->array[i]->freq);
    printf("---------end.\n");
}
 
void printOrderedHashTable(struct hashTable *ht){
    printf("Printing sorted hash table:\n");
    //add sorting
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
        if( ht->array[i]!=NULL )
            printf("%s: %d\n", ht->array[i]->key, ht->array[i]->freq);
    printf("---------end.\n");
}
 
int insert(struct hashTable *ht, keyType key){
    int index;
    int i=0;
    int collision=1;
    while( collision && i<m ){
        index = hash(key, i);
        if( ht->array[index]!=NULL ){
            if( ht->array[index]!=key ){
                collision=1;
                i++;
            }else
                ht->array[index]->freq++;
        }else{
            collision = 0;
            hashElem *s;
            s=malloc(sizeof(hashElem));
            s->freq++;
            s->key = key;
            ht->array[index] = s;
            ht->N++;
        }
    }
    if( collision==1 )
        return -1;
    else
        return 1;
}
 
int main(){
    struct hashTable *ht;
    ht=createHashTable();
 
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("GNU.txt", "r"); //you can find the file at the end
    if( f==NULL )
        printf("Error in file opening.\n");
 
    char input[255];
    printf("Reading file...\n");
    while( !feof(f) && ht->N<m ){
        fscanf(f, "%s", input);
        insert(ht, input);
    }
    fclose(f);
 
    printHashTable(ht);
    //printOrderedHashTable(ht);
    freeHashTable(ht);
    return 0;
}
 
 
 
// GNU.txt file
 
                    GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE
                       Version 3, 29 June 2007
 
 Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc. <http://fsf.org/>
 Everyone is permitted to copy and distribute verbatim copies
 of this license document, but changing it is not allowed.
 
                            Preamble
 
  The GNU General Public License is a free, copyleft license for
software and other kinds of works.
 
  The licenses for most software and other practical works are designed
to take away your freedom to share and change the works.  By contrast,
the GNU General Public License is intended to guarantee your freedom to
share and change all versions of a program to make sure it remains free
software for all its users.  We, the Free Software Foundation, use the
GNU General Public License for most of our software; it applies also to
any other work released this way by its authors.  You can apply it to
your programs, too.
 
  When we speak of free software, we are referring to freedom, not
price.  Our General Public Licenses are designed to make sure that you
have the freedom to distribute copies of free software (and charge for
them if you wish), that you receive source code or can get it if you
want it, that you can change the software or use pieces of it in new
free programs, and that you know you can do these things.
 
  To protect your rights, we need to prevent others from denying you
these rights or asking you to surrender the rights.  Therefore, you have
certain responsibilities if you distribute copies of the software, or if
you modify it: responsibilities to respect the freedom of others.
 
  For example, if you distribute copies of such a program, whether
gratis or for a fee, you must pass on to the recipients the same
freedoms that you received.  You must make sure that they, too, receive
or can get the source code.  And you must show them these terms so they
know their rights.
 
  Developers that use the GNU GPL protect your rights with two steps:
(1) assert copyright on the software, and (2) offer you this License
giving you legal permission to copy, distribute and/or modify it.
 
  For the developers' and authors' protection, the GPL clearly explains
that there is no warranty for this free software.  For both users' and
authors' sake, the GPL requires that modified versions be marked as
changed, so that their problems will not be attributed erroneously to
authors of previous versions.
 
  Some devices are designed to deny users access to install or run
modified versions of the software inside them, although the manufacturer
can do so.  This is fundamentally incompatible with the aim of
protecting users' freedom to change the software.  The systematic
pattern of such abuse occurs in the area of products for individuals to
use, which is precisely where it is most unacceptable.  Therefore, we
have designed this version of the GPL to prohibit the practice for those
products.  If such problems arise substantially in other domains, we
stand ready to extend this provision to those domains in future versions
of the GPL, as needed to protect the freedom of users.
 
  Finally, every program is threatened constantly by software patents.
States should not allow patents to restrict development and use of
software on general-purpose computers, but in those that do, we wish to
avoid the special danger that patents applied to a free program could
make it effectively proprietary.  To prevent this, the GPL assures that
patents cannot be used to render the program non-free.
 
  The precise terms and conditions for copying, distribution and
modification follow.
 
                       TERMS AND CONDITIONS
 
  0. Definitions.
 
  "This License" refers to version 3 of the GNU General Public License.
 
  "Copyright" also means copyright-like laws that apply to other kinds of
works, such as semiconductor masks.
 
  "The Program" refers to any copyrightable work licensed under this
License.  Each licensee is addressed as "you".  "Licensees" and
"recipients" may be individuals or organizations.
 
  To "modify" a work means to copy from or adapt all or part of the work
in a fashion requiring copyright permission, other than the making of an
exact copy.  The resulting work is called a "modified version" of the
earlier work or a work "based on" the earlier work.
 
  A "covered work" means either the unmodified Program or a work based
on the Program.
 
  To "propagate" a work means to do anything with it that, without
permission, would make you directly or secondarily liable for
infringement under applicable copyright law, except executing it on a
computer or modifying a private copy.  Propagation includes copying,
distribution (with or without modification), making available to the
public, and in some countries other activities as well.
 
  To "convey" a work means any kind of propagation that enables other
parties to make or receive copies.  Mere interaction with a user through
a computer network, with no transfer of a copy, is not conveying.
 
  An interactive user interface displays "Appropriate Legal Notices"
to the extent that it includesded), that licensees may convey the
work under this License, and how to view a copy of this License.  If
the interface presents a list of user commands or options, such as a
menu, a prominent item in the list meets this criterion.
 
  1. Source Code.
 
  The "source code" for a work means the preferred form of the work
for making modifications to it.  "Object code" means any non-source
form of a work.
 
  A "Standard Interface" means an interface that either is an official
standard defined by a recognized standards body, or, in the case of
interfaces specified for a particular programming language, one that
is widely used among developers working in that language.
 
  The "System Libraries" of an executable work include anything, other
than the work as a whole, that (a) is included in the normal form of
packaging a Major Component, but which is not part of that Major
Component, and (b) serves only to enable use of the work with that
Major Component, or to implement a Standard Interface for which an
implementation is available to the public in source code form.  A
"Major Component", in this context, means a major essential component
(kernel, window system, and so on) of the specific operating system
(if any) on which the executable work runs, or a compiler used to
produce the work, or an object code interpreter used to run it.
 
  The "Corresponding Source" for a work in object code form means all
the source code needed to generate, install, and (for an executable
work) run the object code and to modify the work, including scripts to
control those activities.  However, it does not include the work's
System Libraries, or general-purpose tools or generally available free
programs which are used unmodified in performing those activities but
which are not part of the work.  For example, Corresponding Source
includes interface definition files associated with source files for
tse explicitly affirms your unlimited
permission to run the unmodified Program.  The output from running a
covered work is covered by this License only if the output, given its
content, constitutes a covered work.  This License acknowledges your
rights of fair use or other equivalent, as provided by copyright law.
 
  You may make, run and propagate covered works that you do not
convey, without conditions so long as your license otherwise opyrighted material outside their relationship with you.
 
  Conveying under any other circumstances is permitted solely under
the conditions stated below.  Sublicensing is not allowed; section 10
makes it unnecessary.
 
  3. Protecting Users' Legal Rights From Anti-Circumvention Law.
 
  No covered work shall be deemed part of an effective technological
measure under any applicable law fulfilling obligations under article
11 of the WIPO copyright treaty adopted on 20 December 1996, or
similar laws prohibiting or restricting circumvention of such
measures.
 
  When you convey a covered work, you waive any legal power to forbid
circumvention of technological measures to the extent such circumvention
is effected by exercising rights under this License with respect to
the covered work, and you disclaim any intention to limit operation or
modification of the work as a means of enforcing, against the work's
users, your or third parties' legal rights to forbid circumvention of
technological measures.
 
  4. Conveying Verbatim Copies.
 
  You may convey verbatim copies of the Program's source code as you
receive it, in any medium, provided that you conspicuously and
appropriately publish on each copy an appropriate copyright notice;
keep intact all notices stating that this License and any
non-permissive terms added in accord with section 7 apply to the code;
keep intact all notices of the absence of any warranty; and give all
recipients a copy of this License along with the Program.
 
  You may charge any price or no price for each copy that you convey,
and you may offer support or warranty protection for a fee.
 
  5. Conveying Modified Source Versions.
 
  You may convey a work based on the Program, or the modifications to
produce it from the Program, in the form of source code under the
terms of section 4, provided that you also meet all of these conditions:
 
    a) The work must carry prominent notices stating that you modified
   it, and giving a relevant date.
 
    b) The work must carry prominent notices stating that it is
    released under this License and any conditions added under section
    7.  This requirement modifies the requirement in section 4 to
    "keep intact all notices".
 
    c) You must license the entire work, as a whole, under this
    License to anyone who comes into possession of a copy.  This
    License will therefore apply, along with any applicable section 7
    additional terms, to the whole of the work, and all its parts,
    regardless of how they are packaged.  This License gives no
    permission to license the work in any other way, but it does not
    invalidate such permission if you have separately received it.
 
    d) If the work has interactive user interfaces, each must display
    Appropriate Legal Notices; however, if the Program has interactive
    interfaces that do not display Appropriate Legal Notices, your
    work need not make them do so.
 
  A compilation of a covered work with other separate and independent
works, which are not by their nature extensions of the covered work,
and which are not combined with it such as to form a larger program,
in or on a volume of a storage or distribution medium, is called an
"aggregate" if the compilation and its resulting copyright are not
used to limit the access or legal rights of the compilation's users
beyond what the individual works permit.  Inclusion of a covered work
in an aggregate does not cause this License to apply to the other
parts of the aggregate.
 
  6. Conveying Non-Source Forms.
 
  You may convey a covered work in object code form under the terms
of sections 4 and 5, provided that you also convey the
machine-readable Corresponding Source under the terms of this License,
in one of these ways:
 
    a) Convey the object code in, or embodied in, a physical product
    (including a physical distribution medium), accompanied by the
    Corresponding Source fixed on a durable physical medium
    customarily use for software interchange.
 
    b) Convey the object code in, or embodied in, a physical product
    (including a physical distribution medium), accompanied by a
    written offer, valid for at least three years and valid for as
    long as you offer spare parts or customer support for that product
    model, to give anyone who possesses the object code either (1) a
    copy of the Corresponding Source for all the software in the
    product that is covered by this License, on a durable physical
    medium customarily used for software interchange, for a price no
    more than your reasonable cost of physically performing this
    conveying of source, or (2) access to copy the
    Corresponding Source from a network server at no charge.
 
    c) Convey individual copies of the object code with a copy of the
    written offer to provide the Corresponding Source.  This
    alternative is allowed only occasionally and noncommercially, less of how the transaction is characterized), the
Corresponding Source conveyed under this section must be accompanied
by the Installation Information.  But this requirement does not apply
if neither you nor any third party retains the ability to install
modified object code on the User Product (for example, the work has
been installed in ROM).
```

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6lE1Y6aRd1XwiMt4) and I got some other errors. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Are you sure this is the warning? `key` is a `char *` in your `struct`  and it matches with `%s`, have you made any change and forget to compile?

Comment: @MikeCAT This is the code if you need to reproduce https://pastebin.com/jPpptdLn

Comment: @David Ranieri that's what bugs me, I checked the program multiple times
This is what the program is telling me too:
warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast
warning: assignment to 'char **' from incompatible pointer type 'keyType' {aka 'char *'} [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the linked code in pastebin:

```
typedef char *keyType;
typedef int valueType;

typedef struct hashElem{
    keyType *key;
    ...
```

Here `keyType` is an alias of `char *`, but then, in the `struct`, you add an extra `*` in `keyType *key;`, this results in:

```
typedef struct hashElem{
    char **key;
```

That's why your compiler complains about:

```
warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char **'
```

Fix-it using:

```
typedef struct hashElem{
    char *key; // As in the snippet showed in your thread :)
```

or

```
typedef struct hashElem{
    keyType key; // Hidding pointers with typedefs is a bad idea
```

Comment: I changed "keyType *key" to "keyType key" and now it seems that there are no warnings. But when i run the program I still get the same result.

Comment: Yes, because you are reserving space for the containers and the list `hashElem`, but you don't reserve space for each element of `hashElem`.  Why don't paste the code here instead of doing it in pastebin?  You will get more help.

Comment: Sorry but I haven't understood my mistake, do i need to create another array to store the elements? 
And thank you for your time, I can't focus right now... this exam is really stressing me out.
By the way you are right, now I pasted the code from pastebin to here.